# Report Builder/SSRS and RDLs - HTML <img> support?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm completely new to SSRS so apologies if this is a silly question. I have an RDL with a HTML placeholder however if I pass an `<img>` tag in the dataset this does not render.

I see on [this Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519562.aspx) article that there is a list of supported tags, which unfortunately doesn't include `<img>`. I've been able to add an image with an external source based on an expression which uses a dataset field so it seems a little strange that you can't use images in HTML placeholders. Is there a workaround for this at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The workaround is exactly what you hinted at: add an image to the report, and set its source based on your dataset. These images can be in a tablix, so repeated for every group or data element.

I don't think of the text placeholders as full "HTML placeholders." They are really text placeholders on which you can choose to honor HTML text formatting codes. Layout, such as tables, and embedded images are not supported.

SSRS is built to handle images as background images or with the Image object.

If you really need inline images in your text, then I would look at something other than SSRS  or investigate some client-side JavaScript hackery.

Comment: Thanks, this is the impression I got from the reading I did. A "full" HTML placeholder would have saved me some refactoring elsewhere, but an image with external source set in a Tablix should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Please vote for this to be supported out of the box!

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/786595/adding-image-and-table-as-html-tags-in-placeholder-of-ssrs-reports

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3113483