# Show HTML with images in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need to put into a SSRS report a field with HTML that contains images.

The HTML is rendered fine, but the images are ignored, i don't know if there are some restrictions to this, the docs are a little vague about this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207057.aspx

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the report viewer to display the report?

Find a similar problem here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15502186/embedded-images-in-ssrs-reports-not-displaying-permissions-issue

also the below link about embedding images on your report 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239394.aspx

Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Hi @BojanB thanks for your reply, well we are not using the report viewer, we are rendering the report on report server, we don't get any error message, but just to clarify a little bit: we use the approach  in this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207057.aspx, basically, we have a text field, and create the placeholder configured to show HTML, from SQLServer we get a result set in which comes an HTML with img tags and absolute paths en src attribute, all the HTML is rendering fine, but the images are ignored.

Comment: In such a case, the src for the image, is not correct, and the image is probably not found from the report. 
Can you add a sample <img tag with a sample source? 
I would try to access the url of the image from a browser directly, from the machine where the reporting services are installed, and check if it is accessible. If it is not, find the correct url to the image, through which it is accessibly, and replace the src of the img tag with the correct one.

Comment: well @BojanB we take the output of the store procedure that has the html and create a html with notepad to verify if the html is valid, because we have doubts about that, but it looks to be fine, therefore we think there is some incompatibility wiht that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referencing the official microsoft page for supported html tags in fields,

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519562%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

It seems that the img tag is not supported in the field with enabled html.

The list of supported tags, taken from the link is below:

**Supported HTML Tags**

The following is a complete list of tags that will render as HTML when defined as placeholder text:

```
Hyperlinks: <A HREF>
Fonts: <FONT>
Header, style and block elements: <H{n}>, <DIV>, <SPAN>,<P>, <DIV>, <LI>, <HN>
Text format: <B>, <I>, <U>, <S>
List handling: <OL>, <UL>, <LI>
```

Thus this is why the img tag is ignored and no error message is shown.

As a workaround, you could add the image separately, (if your design allows so), by parsing the image url from the html, and add it into a separate column of your tablix or list. If you have one that is.

Visit link below on how to add an external image:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220527.aspx

Possible duplicate of this question:

[Report Builder/SSRS and RDLs - HTML <img> support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270332/report-builder-ssrs-and-rdls-html-img-support).

Comment: Hi @BojanB, thanks for your help! that's what i think, it is a limited tool in some things. Finally our need was convert a PDF file from HTML data from SQLSevrer, and that's very easy with the metadata web service in SSRS, but we change the approach to comercial library to create this file http://www.essentialobjects.com/Products/EOPdf/Default.aspx it is a little expensive but works fine.

Comment: np ccuenca Glad it helped, as i mentioned you could make it through reporting services as well, but you would have to reproduce the HTML design, in the report designer, adding the images, as image in the report designer, with external url.  Of course if the complexity is too big, cost analysis would say to proceed with commercial html to pdf converter.